# How to get json log using retrofit2 in Android studio?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I read https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses and made it.

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.interceptors().add(logging);

    client = builder.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(LoginApiService.Login_API_URL)
            .build();
```

But it's returned result like

```
09-08 05:12:24.219 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: --> POST http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/rest-auth/login/ http/1.1
09-08 05:12:24.219 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
09-08 05:12:24.219 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 46
09-08 05:12:24.219 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: --> END POST
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/rest-auth/login/ (96ms)
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 20:11:27 GMT
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Allow: POST, OPTIONS
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
09-08 05:12:24.314 25389-26089/com.example.keepair.myapplication D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

It's not enough.

Because i'm using RESTful api and json type,

1. I want check json request that i send to api and json response that comes from api. For example, { "hi" : "bye" }, full information of json request and response.
2. Additionally i want to know exactly what has send through header from my application.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the code of [HttpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L130):

```
public HttpLoggingInterceptor setLevel(Level level) {
    if (level == null) throw new NullPointerException("level == null. Use Level.NONE instead.");
    this.level = level;
    return this;
}
```

You'll see that every time you are calling this method you are overriding the last call, so doing this:

```
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
```

Sets the level to `Level.HEADERS`.
Which is exactly what's happening in your logs, you see only the headers.
Just remove that (2nd) line and you'll have `Level.BODY` which is what you're looking for.